# progress bar for Hibernation in Windows Seven

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, progress

On XP, during hibernation a progress bar shows me how long I have to wait for completing the operation.
On Seven, I see no progress bar and the monitor turn off at once while the OS saves the ram on the disk.
Same thing during the wake up process after the hibernation.
Is it possible to have the progress bar for hibernation and following wake up on Seven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature was removed as of Windows Vista, and was not added back into Windows 7.  It does not appear that this feature is able to be added back in.  See:  http://www.adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2006/12/26/919.aspx

Answer (score 2):

## No progress bar

That's *by design* since Windows Vista:

> The system turns off the video functionality before the sleep or hibernation process continues. You can still view the power indicators or the status indicators that your computer provides to determine whether the computer is asleep or in hibernation.
>
> <sub>Source: [No progress bar is displayed when you put a Windows Vista-based computer to sleep or into hibernation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958103/en-us)</sub>

While you can't have a hibernation progress bar, you can *still* disable the standard animation shown during the resume process, and display a basic progress indicator instead. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7).
2. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   bcdedit /set {resumeloadersettings} bootux basic
   ```
3. Restart Windows to apply the changes.

### Additional information

> The `bcdedit /set` command sets a boot entry option value in the Windows boot configuration data store (BCD) for Windows Vista, Windows 7,  [and later].
>
> `bootux [ disabled | basic | standard ]`
>
> Controls the boot screen animation. The possible values are `disabled`, `basic`, and `standard`.
>
> **Note**  Not supported in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.
>
> <sub>Source: [BCDEdit /set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

Comment: It's pretty dumb that they would remove something convenient like that. But that's what Microsoft has been doing for a while now.